# How do I pause a NodeJS script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, read-eval-print-loop

I created a script in Javascript using Node.js to scrape some data from a website overnight.  We'll, I'm at 67% and it's going to take about 5-6 more hours to finish.  But I have enough data at the moment that I'd like to stop it.

Is there a way to pause script execution into a Node REPL session and inspect the variables?  Or something similar?

(I'm scraping data into an array).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put Node in debug mode (which can pause execution) by sending a USR1 signal to it. Check out https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector/

1. find the PID of your node process: `ps -x | grep node`
2. send a USR1 signal to the process: `kill -s USR1 $pid`
3. start node-inspector: `node-inspector &`
4. open a browser on `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858`
5. click pause in the top right corner

Comment: My process is stuck :(  It printed "Error 0" and the debugging interface isn't showing anything.  I'm not sure how to resume the process.

Comment: Well crap.  I screwed something up and the process quit.  Ugh.  Looks like I've got another 24 hours.  Thanks though -- I guess I just didn't know how to use it.